# Is is possible to connect and read FROM a VGA signal with raspberry PI?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have somewhat of the opposite of the popular Raspberry Pi question.. I want to know if it's possible to read *from* a VGA connection.

I want to be able to connect the VGA output from a computer to my Raspberry PI and do some processing on the video signal that it's sending.

Comment: Try the related StackExchange sites [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for programming.

Comment: 640x480 VGA signal has ~30MHz dot clock so you need very fast ADC with big enough FIFO and then read slowly, or use slower ADC and oversample (at cost of framerate) however all this requires very precise timings which I am afraid Rasbperry PI is not a very good choice for... In case you ignore analog and use just digital values of RGB then you can ignore ADC reducing to 8 colors however you still need to read FAST, shift register could help divide the read frequency to usable values ... if you got 3 serial ports at disposal they could be used for this ...

Answer (score 0):

Not without added hardware (specifically, a fast ADC connected to a fast data bus on the RPi)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first dip into the hardware world (I've had my Pi for about 2 hours now :) I'm feeling pretty dense). Could you give me an example of an ADC and how it would connect?